# When making a cocoapod,` pod lib lint` failed.

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

[image]

this is my podspec,It is important to that in KZNetwork.framework i have import JsonModelTranfer.framework.
i don't know how to fill in the podspec

> s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
>
> s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/LiuXiangJing/KZNetwork.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
>
> s.vendored_frameworks = 'JsonModelTranfer.framework','KZNetwork.framework'
>
> s.frameworks = "Foundation", "CoreData","UIKit"

Comment: Please "use pod lib lint --verbose" to get detailed logs and post the full log here to let us know whats happening in the background

Comment: please click the image ,thanks

Comment: seems like build failed due to can't find symbols for architecture x86_64. can you try "pod lib lint --verbose --use-libraries" ?

Comment: yes ,i get the same error . i have check my framework is support for architecture x86_64

Comment: i want to know if one framework import  anther framework. how to set the podspec

Comment: you mean like this ?  s.dependency 'SomeOtherPod'

Comment: yes,but i mean the two frameowrk is in  a cocoapod

Comment: use it like:  
s.dependency 'SomeOtherPod'
s.dependency 'SomeOtherPod2'